# marinated vegetables on food dehydrators?

Tags: jerky, dehydrating

So there's a party I'm going to and I promised to make jerkies, but a few of them are vegans.

I'm wondering if there are vegetables (or anything non-meat) that can be marinated with roughly the same kind of stuff you use for jerkies, and then dehydrated to become some kind of tasty, savory snack?

I once had some pretty tasty dried peas which were quite savory, would using the same kind of marinade with jerkies and putting them on the dehydrator work? They were pretty crunchy, but the last time I tried dehydrating banana slices they ended up being rather chewy instead.

Comment: I don't have an answer because I didn't marinate them but sweet corn (we use frozen) is delicious when dried. If we let them our kids would eat it all in one sitting as a snack.

Comment: I am sure you can do it with raspberries, but the result is sweet: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YT8WAJZcUTM. You can try to do it with a vegetable, by adding marinade, pectin and acid to the puree before dehydrating, but it will definitely need lots of tries and tweaking to get it right.

Comment: I'd consider doing tomatoes -- I've never done it myself, but I've always felt that sundried tomatoes have something jerkeyish about them...

Comment: Banana's in a home dehydrator are chewy.  The ones you buy at the store I've been told are fried somewhat to give that crunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about tofu? It can be "jerkyfied" pretty easily. For example: http://www.ehow.com/how_2128547_make-tofu-jerky.html